# Are all matrices A and B ($3x3$), such that $B = A * 10$ congruent over field $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

As in the title. I know that over field $\mathbb{R}$ for 2 matrices to be congruent they need the same rank and signature. However, I don't know how to proceed over field $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$.

Comment: So, if it works as in $\mathbb{R}$ then it should be true for every version of B ($B = A$, $B = 2A$, $B = 3A$, $B = 4A$, $B = 5A$ etc.). Because I can always take an Id matrix C of square roots to equation $B = C^T * A * C$. Am I right?

Comment: But, square roots do not exist over field $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$. So it will be true for $B = A$, $B = 4A$, $B = 9A$. Not for $B = 10A$.

Comment: Can anybody confirm that?